# Python facebook sdk to fetch profile pictures and friend lists?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, download

I am using this library to access some data in facebook.
https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk
in particular I would be interested in my friends' friend lists and in fetching their profile pictures.

I did not have success trying

```
graph.get_connections(myFriendId, "friends")
```

It seems to me that the GraphAPI does not allow this at all.
However since I have access to this information by browsing the web there should be a simple systematic way to retrieve this data.
Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve your friends of friends. You can only retrieve from friends of the authenticated user. The API is not a reflection of your facebook.com experience.